# Foundation Orbit - Images not showing

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use the orbit feature in foundation 5. The loader seems to work but images don't load. I've inspected it and the link to images seems to be fine and i seem to have all the up to date JavaScript files needed for it to work.

Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/p7PXS/

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="slideshow-wrapper preloader">
        <ul data-orbit  data-options="animation:fade;
                  pause_on_hover:false;
                  animation_speed:1000;
                  navigation_arrows:true;
                  bullets:true;">

              <li>
                 <img src="img/bodymetrix.jpg">

              </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="img/highgate.jpg">

              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you add some working image URLs, the problem you describe is not exhibited. http://jsfiddle.net/p7PXS/1/

Comment: your `src=""`s are pointing at *relative* URLs.. are the images where you think they are, *relative* to the current page?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing those files from your working directory.
When you add a web link it works fine.

Comment: See what you mean about adding an external link. But my files are definitely in the right place and correctly mapped to the files